# how to convert image to dataset to process machine learning

Tags: python, image, numpy, image-processing, machine-learning

How to convert a image to datasets or numpy array and to predict by fiting it to clf

```
import PIL as pillow
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm

infilename=input()
im=Image.open(infilename)
imarr=np.array(im)
flatim=imarr.flatten('F')

clf=svm.SVC(gamma=0.0001,C=100)
x,y=im.size

#how to fit the numpy array to clf 
clf.fit(flatim[:-1],flatim[:-1])
print("prediction:",clf.predict(flatim[-1]))
plt.imshow(flatim,camp=plt.cm.gray_r,interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

Anyone please and thanks!!!

Comment: can you detail more the exact problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

there is no other reason of using SVM on a single image except for fun of doing it.  Here are the fixes I did.  1) use .convert("L") to convert the image as 2D array grayscale. 2) created a dummy target variable y as randomized 1D array.  3) fix type error displaying the image again (plt.imshow) cmap (instead of camp) and im (instead of flatim)

```
import PIL as pillow
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import svm

im=Image.open("sample.jpg").convert("L")
imarr=np.array(im)
flatim=imarr.flatten('F')

clf=svm.SVC()
#X,y=im.size
X = imarr
y = np.random.randint(2, size=imarr.shape[0])
clf.fit(X, y)

#how to fit the numpy array to clf 
#clf.fit(flatim[:-1],flatim[:-1])
# I HAVE NO IDEA WHAT I"M DOING HERE!
print("prediction:", clf.predict(X[-2:-1]))
plt.imshow(im,cmap=plt.cm.gray_r,interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

I see a good example in scikit-learn [website](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html) of using SVM. I guess this is what you are trying to copy. Isn't?